# Find specific sibling of an element

Tags: python, find, beautifulsoup, findall

I have the following structure of an XML page:

```
<address>
<city>Anaheim</city>
<state>California</state>
<zip>92801</zip>
<country>United States</country>
</address>

<address>
<city>Berkley</city>
<state>California</state>
<zip>94705</zip>
<country>United States</country>
</address>
```

I would like to get only the values of the city tags, where the zip tag value meets a condition.
For example I need those city names, where the zip=92801.

Is there a simple way in python to do this?

Comment: I would be particularly interested in BeautifulSoup solutions, because I am parsing other parts of the website with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Beautiful Soup instead:

```
my_string = '''
<root>
  <address>
    <city>Anaheim</city>
    <state>California</state>
    <zip>92801</zip>
    <country>United States</country>
  </address>
  <address>
    <city>Berkley</city>
    <state>California</state>
    <zip>94705</zip>
    <country>United States</country>
  </address>
</root>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string, 'html.parser')
desired_zips = soup.findAll('zip', text="92801")
cities = []
for zip_tag in desired_zips:
    cities.append(zip_tag.findPreviousSibling('city'))

print(cities)
```

**Output:**

```
[<city>Anaheim</city>]
```

Note: you could write this `for` loop into a list comprehension, but it looks clunky and unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

This will achieve the desired results:

```
my_string = '''
  <root>
    <address>
      <city>Anaheim</city>
      <state>California</state>
      <zip>92801</zip>
      <country>United States</country>
    </address>
    <address>
      <city>Berkley</city>
      <state>California</state>
      <zip>94705</zip>
      <country>United States</country>
    </address>
  </root>
'''

from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(my_string)
cities = root.xpath('.//zip[text()="92801"]/preceding-sibling::city')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use `ElementTree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

filtered_addresses = []
for address in root.findall('address'):
    if address.get('zip') == '92801':
        filtered_addresses.append(address)
```